# Intellij Can't open maven project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When my laptop installed windows updates yesterday i'm unable to open my maven project that i've benn working on anymore or even creating one. But i can open other projects. When i click on files --> open and when i choose my project and click 'OK' nothing happens (not even an error message). I try to retart my pc still got nothing. i've even delete my project and recolned it from the github repository still got nothing. And i'm not even able to import 
I hope i gave enough details so you'd be able to resolve my problem.
Thanks for helping.

---

well i actually can't open my project to do that i.e(to go to file --> invalidate caches/Restart)

i only have this

[image]

i can open other projects but not the one that i'm working on. i.e the maven project

---

i'm unable to import my maven project to refresh

[image]

i can't click next to import the project

and my project doesn't have yet any .idea or .iml because i can't open it with intellij to have those files

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory in the project root and import/open from `pom.xml` file. If it doesn't work, share the logs ([idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)).

Comment: don't have any .idea directory

Comment: How do you open the Maven project then? Do you point IDE to `pom.xml` file? Are there any errors in idea.log?

Comment: yes i do have a pom.xml

Comment: but i don't know what is a 'point IDE to pom.xml'

Comment: Import Project from the Welcome Screen, choose pom.xml file in the file chooser.

Comment: i don't have the project in the welcome screen because it can't be open to be added into the welcome screen

Comment: 1. [Import Project](https://i.imgur.com/anKNR86.png). 2. [Select pom.xml file](https://i.imgur.com/7aIwSUj.png). What happens?

Comment: it opens a dialogue box with many options but i can't click on next. when i click nothing happens!

Comment: Please share the logs: Help | Compress Logs and Show in ... or [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: shouldn't we go in private in order to share this?

Comment: It's better to report such issues via IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.

Comment: ok thnak you...

Answer (score 1):

Open Intellij IDE, Go to

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

.
Once it gets restarted, import the maven project and refresh the project by clicking Maven tab which is visible in the right side.

If above does not work, go to your project and delete all .iml and .idea folder and then reimport the project.